# Unifilar (non-stranded) copper wires flexibilty

Tags: wire, copper, flexible, awg

we all know the 26 AWG wires that come inside UTP cables. Those surely are flexible. But what a bout an AWG 15-16 such copper wire, is it flexible enough to use as feeding cable for the 12 V car lighter socket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with solid core wires is they are prone to breakage through repeated mechanical flexing. If your application has any moment of the cable, the wire could break after installation.

If you're fine with the risk of breakage than use it.

On a side note Solid UTP cables should not be used for the connection between your computer and the wall for this reason, only use stranded UTP cables.  Walking on solid core UTP cables is also a great way to break them.

Another 'nother side not, as with all cables, make sure you properly crimp and strip the ends off of wires, any knicks or improper crimping can also fatigue the wire and cause it to break in the future.

This manual is a great resource for tips on how to handle wiring correctly.
[Student Workbook for Crimp, Cable and Harnessing](https://prod.nais.nasa.gov/eps/eps_data/149570-OTHER-001-006.pdf)

Comment: Is there any calculator to relate flexing tolerance with the number (and diameter of) wire strands and bending radius? (shopping question :-(  )

Comment: @AndrewMorton too many late nights, I'll fix that

Comment: @AliChen No but that would be awsome if there was. I know just from handling the solid core wires are liable to breakage after tens of flexes. If you have stranded you are much much better off, they take much more abuse.

Comment: ugh, but I have never had a broken UTP wire in the middle; I  break them from time to time when connecting them to some other wires, sure, and the computer uses exactly those thin solid UTP wires with tremendous success, and the stranded cable's individual strands are... about the thickness of the solid UTB wire :-/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the question of how "much more abuse". It will obviously depend as well on copper alloy in use, so you never know. I found some published MIL-spec guides (from 60's and 70's), but it is difficult to comprehend and relate their data to modern wires. Some companies are selling stranded 18AWG wire sustaining 20,000,000 flexing cycles (of unknown bending radius), some sources say 3-4,000 cycles break it. Hopefully someone knows more about this stuff here.

Comment: @kellogs, you haven't broken the wires in middle because the bending radius in the "middle" is much bigger than near the connectors, where the most bending usually occurs.

Comment: @AliChen ok, how about the vibrations ? The wire will end up on a PCB 'spring clamp' terminal block; would it be better to have this clamp a solid core or a stranded core vibration wise ?

Comment: See this: https://prod.nais.nasa.gov/eps/eps_data/149570-OTHER-001-006.pdf for tips on reducing vibrations and properly handling wire

Comment: This is getting into the topic "metal fatigue" and it's a relatively "new" subject - only seriously worked on after some aircraft stopped flying catastrophically....

Comment: Huh, aircraft catastrophes ? NASA documents ?... I must be getting overly concerned with these connectors and cable things. Guess I'll go with the stranded core, it will probably get better clamped in place than the solid core.

Comment: Yeah, probably more than you wanted, but you *are talking to engineers* here